# Missing icons on security.stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Upvote, downvote, favorite, and many more icons are missing on security.stackexchange.com

[image: Missing icons]

It looks like the [svg sprite](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/security/img/sprites.svg?v=68dca870609d) is missing `x="0px" y="0px" width="160px" height="500px"` on its `<svg>` tag as on [Meta's spritesheet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/content/Sites/stackexchangemeta/img/sprites.svg?v=bb0497e70aa3).

Comment: Someone also posted the issue on security.meta: https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2777/sprites-not-showing-up-any-more

Comment: It is the most secure UI. You don't know what you can do!

Comment: Indeed. Security through obscurity at it's finest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whoops!

There was a bad image in the deploy that caused this. All good now.

(btw - there is no need to cross post bugs here, all meta sites are monitored for bugs)